# How to fix 'JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED')'

Tags: java, docker, jms, mq

I am running a Docker container with MQ 7.1 on it and I am trying to send a test message to the queue using a Java application that will send a message. The docker container is running on a RHEL server and I am trying to send a message from my Windows PC using the Java application in Eclipse locally.

I am tripping up when creating the MQQueueConnection, as I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager '' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'x.x.x.x(1414)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:516)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:216)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.<init>(WMQConnection.java:423)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6772)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6151)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:280)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6143)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:115)
    at mq.MQMessageSender.main(MQMessageSender.java:107)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:204)
    ... 7 more
```

I have tried to change the authorization of the 'nobody' user and try open the gates with the following command but its not working:

`setmqaut -m QM1 -t qmgr -p 'nobody' +allmqi`

Some info below:

```
Queue Manager: QM1
Queues: Q1, Q2
Channel name: MESSAGESENDER
```

Answer (score 1):

Just fixed this error. I added the 'mqm' user I was using on the docker container to my `createQueueConnection` call like this:

```
MQQueueConnection queueConn = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection("admin1", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the typical error when the MQ client does not provide conn creds, it can also happen in the WebSphere log when you forgot to specify creds in the Integrated Console